# Implementing a custom Android sensor hal

Tags: android, sensors, hal

I have a project to change the interface implementation of the android sensor hal layer of the cloud phone, the original Poll() function is to get data from the physical layer of the sensor, I have changed it to get the sensor data from the real physical machine and then transfer it to the server, the poll() function of the cloud phone gets the data from the server. The real android phone sends the data to the server and stores it in the cache, the poll() function of the cloud phone reads the data from this cache and returns it to the upper layer application. But I have a question, is to open multiple apps at the same time, will go to call poll() function to get sensor data from the cache, so how to ensure that each application can only read their own registered activated sensor data?

I would like to know how android itself Poll() function prevents multiple apps from grabbing sensor data, does android itself have a corresponding isolation mechanism?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.